# Cannot generate the signed APK due to some warning

Tags: android, signed-apk

While generating a signed APK I got these warinings

```
Warning: org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.ManagementFactory
Warning: org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.ThreadMXBean
Warning: org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.ThreadMXBean
Warning: org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.ManagementFactory
Warning: org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.ThreadMXBean
Warning: org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.ThreadMXBean
Warning: org.junit.rules.DisableOnDebug: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.ManagementFactory
Warning: org.junit.rules.DisableOnDebug: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.RuntimeMXBean
Warning: org.junit.rules.DisableOnDebug: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.ManagementFactory
Warning: org.junit.rules.DisableOnDebug: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.RuntimeMXBean
```

What should I do to avoid these warnings? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: this warning can be avoided..!!

Comment: I will check this and let youknow

Comment: How this question will be duplicate. Its mention about the jar warning for simpleframework

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the proguard-rules.pro file add

```
-dontwarn java.lang.management.**
```

This warning can be avoid